# Shell Script to rename current working directory with given name

Tags: shell-script, directory, rename

If present directory is `DIR/` and new name `project1/` is passed through argument, the present directory name should be replaced by `project1`.

Comment: Have you try to use `mv` command?

Comment: Read the manpage for `mv`: `man mv`. Note that you first should leave the directory to rename it.

Answer (score 4):

If you rename the current working directory, most shells will fail to notice the change (in their `$PWD` variable or their prompt for instance), so it would be a better idea to use a function instead of a script so you can notify the shell of the change after you've done it, like:

```
rename_cwd() {
  cd . || return
  new_dir=${PWD%/*}/$1
  mv -- "$PWD" "$new_dir" &&
    cd -- "$new_dir"
}
```

That assumes the current directory is not `/` and that the target directory doesn't already exist (see the `-T` option with GNU `mv` to improve matters in that case).

Note that under some circumstances, `$PWD` may be out of sync with the reality so the code above may end up changing the current working directory. The `cd .` is there to reduce the likelihood of it in some shells.

Answer (score 2):

I got it by below code

```
mv -T "$PWD" "../$1"
```

Argument passed as

```
./rename_pwd.sh dir1
```

Then

```
cd ..

ls
```

It shows

```
dir1
```

Comment: Good point. Note however that if $PWD is a symlink, for instance, `/a/b/c` symlink to `/1/2/3` (where `/1/2/3` is not a symlink itself), then `rename_pwd.sh d` will do the equivalent of `mv /a/b/c /1/2/d`. Doing a `mv /a/b/c /a/b/d` (like in my answer) would probably be closer to what one would generally want.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote [this](https://github.com/MNFaust/BASH-Scripts/blob/master/rename_utility.sh) a long time ago. It's a crappy little script but, it will rename stuff for you.